# Autocomplete not working for apache spark in java vscode

Tags: java, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, indexing, autocomplete

So I have been trying to learn apache spark but for some reason I cannot seem to get autocomplete working for the things that I haven't already imported, I don't know it seems to be an indexing issue, how do I make sure vscode indexes all my dependencies.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see its not showing me Dataset from spark.sql.dataset
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz2jB.png
I know I can add it manually but it gets a little annoying, I have enough ram and a good enough processor, so I have no idea why is this not working.